# How to detect that stdout is closed (when telnet session is closed) in my program?

Tags: c, linux, stdout

I am developing a program on embedded Linux. My program is a deamon and has a log function that outputs the log with `printf` (stdout output).

So If I open a telnet session on the embedded Linux system and then launch my program I will get the output displayed in the telnet session. I am wondering what will happen to the output if I close the telnet session. Where is the output redirected to?

And is it possible to check if *stdout* is closed when I close the telnet session? In order to avoid my log function to be executed when the stdout is closed.

Comment: A deamon should not print to stdout at all... Nevertheless, you might get a runtime-error. You can actually determine the characters written by checking the return-value of printf. Try that... See section [return](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Answer (score 0):

[`ftell`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/ftell.html) might be handy here. One can check for the `EBADF` error and stop any further writes. In C, writing to a file handle that is not open leads to undefined behavior.

I am not sure if closing your telnet session is a problem, because the environment itself might get killed if you are using a shell-like environment. I am not too sure about the behavior there.

Comment: is it possible to make my test with that `if(ftell(stdout)==-1)` because the `ftell` return `long` ?

Comment: I tried the `ftell(stdout)` but it returns -1 when my session telnet is still opend and I did not closed yet

Answer (score 0):

Daemons should handle SIGHUP, which is the signal the terminal will generate on closing. If you don't handle that, your daemon will terminate with telnet.

And if the fd gets disconnected, the output will be lost. In general for logging you should use the syslog() call.

Comment: I launch my daemon with `$ my_daemon &` so the close of terminal will not cause the stop of my daemon

Comment: Have you tried? Perhaps you are using a wacky terminal. The "&" at the end has nothing to do with SIGHUP.